# Why do people not connect all their cycles nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

So I downloaded this [blend](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ezs3ac34a26aa3f5ce6650303da779cb7c9b/Blender+Guru/BlenderGuru+-+Baking_PrisonHall.blend) file to figure out how to bake out textures. In the process I see that he has some very complex node set-ups all to end up seeing them not connected at the end. Why have such complex node systems just to not connect them?

This is not the first time I've seen this. Please someone explain this logic to me.

Comment: Those nodes are probably left over from trying different things... Unconnected nodes have no effect.

Comment: Thanks just confirmed what I expected to be true. Not knowing was driving me crazy.

Comment: The only possible way I can think of for disconnected nodes to be used is [baking](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/599). However this only utilizes a single texture node. Probably just leftover nodes as cegaton said.

Comment: Since scripts can [access and edit nodes](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32162/5334) I wonder if nodes that are disconnected at the moment are 100% guaranteed in all cases to be *forever unused?* Of course not likely, but maybe it's possible somewhere in the universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the disconnected nodes are the original materials (textured, with normal maps, diffuse and glossy shader), the connected nodes are the baked materials (baked texture plugged to emission shader)